# Formal finite sum for integration on k-chains

Tags: differential-geometry, integration, differential-forms

This question is related to the integration of differential forms on chains, as exposed in the document at: http://www.math.upenn.edu/~ryblair/Math%20600/papers/Lec17.pdf . The author gives the following definitions:

*Let U be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. A singular k-cube in U is a continuous map
$c:[0,1]^k\rightarrow U$*

*A (singular) k-chain in U is a formal finite sum of singular k-cubes in U with integer coefficients, such as $2c^1+ 3c^2−4c^3$.*

Such a decomposition is used later for the integration of a differential form $\omega$, in:

$\int_c \omega = \sum a_i\int_{c_i} \omega$

What is, in simple terms, the definition (or at least an intuition) of a formal finite sum of functions in this context ? Is a [Free Abelian Group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_abelian_group) involved, with which group operation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Singular $k$-chains form a free abelian group generated by singular $k$-cubes. You can define integral of differential forms over singular $k$-cubes, and the integral over chains is just the $\mathbb{Z}$-linear extension of the integral maps over cubes.

Comment: OK, but what is the meaning of $2c^1$ for example ? How is it related to $c^1$ ?

Comment: As $c_i$ are functions, what is the group operation ?

Comment: @johndeas, "formal" means that we consider expressions of the form $\sum n_ic_i$, where $n_i$ are integers and $c_i$ are your cubes. The group operation does not change $c_i$, we merely add up the coefficients of $c_i$. An analogy would the free abelian group generated by fruits. An element in this group could then be "1 apple + 1 orange", and the sum of "1 apple + 1 orange" + "3 orange + 1 kiwi + 1 banana" is just "1 apple + 4 orange + 1 kiwi + 1 banana".

Comment: I am sorry I still do not get it. What kind of object is $2c^1$ for example, if it is not a function ?

Comment: In the case of $2c^1$, does this mean that you integrate two times over the same place ?

Comment: @johndeas, you can think about it that way if you want to, although  strictly speaking that would be the interpretation of $\int_{2c^1}$ rather than $2c^1$ itself. In the analogy of fruits, "two oranges" is not really a type of fruit in itself; you just have two things of the same kind put together in some way. Same thing happens here.

Comment: I think I got it now. Your example really helps, thank you !